# I installed GUI programs, but no shortcuts were added—how can I execute them?

Tags: software-installation

I installed DeVede and DVD Author. I am clueless on how to use them as there were no shortcuts created, when using Add/Remove programs. Did they not install correctly? What is the name of the programs directory? Do they need to be launched in command line? What is the command to execute or, is there an executable in program folder, that was created in a directory I cannot find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all the files that are installed by the package with:

```
dpkg -L [package-name]
```

You are looking for executable files, which are placed in `bin` directories, so you can filter that this way:

```
dpkg -L [package-name] | grep "bin/"
```

There may be more than one thing listed, but this should narrow it down enough that you can try them from a GUI terminal until you get the right one.

Comment: Thank you! It showed me they were not installed for some reason. Just tried sudo apt-get install and it's installing now